# What means electrostatic in vacuum?

Tags: electrostatics, vacuum

Can you explain what's the concept of electrostatic in vacuum?

And exists electrostatic in no vacuum?

If exists

What's the difference between electrostatic in vacuum and electrostatic in no vacuum?

Comment: Can you imagine a charge and its field in the vacuum of outer space? Can you imagine a charge and its field in, say, water? Can you imagine that the water affects the field because water is made of charged particles? Please clarify what confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

Electrostatic means that there are no moving charges.